# Importing High/Low/Close Data into Excel (Trading/Futures "Coding")

Tags: excel, stocks, trading

I want to import into Excel High/Low/Close data for, let's say, the Wheat contracts of 2009.

I'm looking to do this in Python, but I will learn another language if it is necessary.

I am a newb to programming for Futures. If the above problem is my goal, how can I achieve it?

P.S. I am not sure where or how to get the data in the first place. This may be a complex problem, so I am posting it in several Reddits/Forums. Any insight anyone can give would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Sparrow

---

Progress Update: 2011-06-22 16:19

[Response from EliteTrader.com user (kanellop)](http://www.elitetrader.com/vb/showthread.php?s=&postid=3217613#post3217613):

> The Major thing is...which is your Data Provider...? 
>   If i suppose that is Reuters DataLink...and you use Metastock...
>   then you must use the Function: Convert of the Downloader and to
>   transfer these Data's to Excel.

To answer his question, I use the ThinkorSwim platform. Data is received and organized by the platform into [price charts such as this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaPxT.jpg).

Neither Reuters DataLink nor Metastock, which kanellop recommends, are free. Thus, it seems a little silly to have ThinkorSwim **and then** pay for a raw data feed. Shouldn't there be a way to rip the historical data from my platform?

Comment: What programming language are you planning on using?

Comment: I'm most familiar with Python, but I'll learn another language if needed. And thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think this is an actionable question until you understand what data source you want to use. One couldn't possibly suggest how to code anything with such an open-ended situation.

Comment: The data source is perhaps the ThinkorSwim platform. Or perhaps the question is, what is the data source that the ThinkorSwim platform uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the futures data you will need a trading API (such as the [T4 API](http://www.ctsfutures.com/t4_api.aspx), btw T4 is free for 14 days) and if you're using C# then serializing the data to a CSV file is trivial.

It goes something like this:

```
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("fileName.csv"))
{
    foreach(Quote q in quotes)// assuming there is a Quote object and a list of quotes
    {
        sw.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2},{3}", q.Open, q.High, q.Low, q.Close);// something of the sort
    }
}
```

The most difficult part you will encounter is using the trading API to pull the necessary data, but it comes with examples (which you will find in the install directory) so you should be able to figure it out in a couple of days or so.

### Update:

What you're asking for is significantly more challenging then using a commercial API. It is possible and you have several options, but none of them are trivial:

1. Scrape directly from the screen: make an application that takes screenshots and extracts the data from the images. Let's just say it's not fun!
2. If it's a desktop application: you can intercept the network traffic that's coming into the application you're using  and even if you're able to do that you may hit a big wall if they're utilizing a secure connection (i.e. encryption of some sort).
3. If it's a web application: you can create a browser in C# and you can scrape the data from the HTML pages that your client gets... if they're using JavaScript, then this becomes SIGNIFICANTLY more complex!

At the end of the day, it will be MUCH cheaper if you just pay a 3rd party to give you the data then actually trying to develop software that "intercepts" the data from ThinkOrSwim.

Comment: Thanks, Liric. That's answers everything perfectly. :)

I'll make use of that 14-day Free Trial, and perhaps one day pay for the API software.

I read your profile and some of your other comments on SO. AI/ML for the markets would be a lot of fun to study.